# An error occurred while running cordova build ios --release (exit code 1)

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, terminal, ionic2

I am trying to build an ionic project using

```
ionic cordova build ios --release
```

, but I am getting BUILD FAILED error.

> The following build commands failed:   Ld /Users/anilram25/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Projectname-dhymtjexvkoysbcnqkakvypnvisi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Projectname.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Projectname.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Projectname
>   normal x86_64 (1 failure) Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild
>   with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/anilram25/Project/0.2.9/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-workspace,Projectname.xcworkspace,-scheme,Projectname,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/anilram25/Project/0.2.9/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/anilram25/Project/0.2.9/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios --release
>   (exit code 1).

Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: can you post the full log

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a development provisioning profile configured in Xcode.

Try to remove and add ios again:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios

ionic cordova platform add ios
```

And make sure you have the latest platform update:

```
ionic cordova platform update ios
```